# How to use vba to switch between open tabs in Lotus Notes?

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-notes

I'm currently trying to generate multiple forms in lotus notes via VBA in a specific database and send them for processing. Due to several notes scripts running when creating/processing the various forms, the only theoretical way that I can imagine this to work would be to have the user open a form, so that the VBA script can tell it to do copies through a button in the form (via the Windows API), then cycle through the open forms, fill them out and submit them one by one.

So far so good, but I'd need to be able to cycle through all the open forms in Notes in order to find the form I want to fill out and set is as active window. I can't seem to find any API that allows a user to go through all the open tabs in a notes window. Would anyone be able to help me on this one, please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the front-end classes (NotesUIWorkspace, NotesUIDatabase,NotesUIDocument, etc.) instead of the back-end classes (NotesSession, NotesDatabase, NotesDocument, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible. There is no way to "cycle" windows via code in Lotus Notes / IBM Notes.

Better turn around your processing: Instead of opening a form for editing just fill it in the backend. Then you don't need Windows API- calls and the Clipboard at all.

of course you can open the filled form afterwards to let the user fill in additional information, but this is not necessary at all as you can also save the document in backend.

Comment: Hi, 
I thought about doing this from the backend, but sadly, if I do, the lotus scripts attached to the creation of a form via button aren't triggered. Non-editable fields I don't have information on that the form usually has pre-filled are kept blank, leaving the form with an incomplete, faulty distribution chain... among other things.

Comment: Is ComputeWithForm only a command that checks whether or not the form is properly filled out? Or did I understand that one incorrectly?
As for filling the information on my own, I don't have the accesses to get to it on my own, sadly. Even if I did, the information can change on a whim without me knowin. That's why there's a lot of scripting inside the forms to prefill the information for the user already.

Comment: The help is not clear on that one: ComputeWithForm does the same as opening, pressing "F9" and saving the document (almost, there are some things that won't work, but you will find out about them)... Just check the return value: If it is true, then the doc is valid, contains all necessary items and can be saved...